# How to use the sqlmap installed from macports?

Tags: python, macports, sqlmap

I installed `sqlmap` from macports 2.3.4 on macOS Sierra 10.12

```
sqlmap @0.9_1 (security, databases, python)
    sqlmap is an open source penetration testing tool.
```

Then found:

```
> sqlmap
zsh: command not found: sqlmap

> python sqlmap.py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'sqlmap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Then I made a try to find the files of sqlmap:(`.` for `/opt/local/`)

```
> find . -name '*sqlmap*'
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/extra/msfauxmod/sqlmap.rb
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/sqlmap.conf
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/sqlmap.py
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/sqlmap.pyc
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/sqlmap.pyo
./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlmap/xml/sqlmap.xsd
./var/macports/distfiles/sqlmap
./var/macports/distfiles/sqlmap/sqlmap-0.9.tar.gz
./var/macports/registry/portfiles/sqlmap-0.9_1
./var/macports/software/sqlmap
./var/macports/software/sqlmap/sqlmap-0.9_1+python27.darwin_16.x86_64.tbz2
./var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/security/sqlmap
```

And I cannot find any executable file in `/opt/local/bin` or `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/`

So how to use the sqlmap installed from macports? Or if I missed some files?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `port contents sqlmap` lists all files installed by the sqlmap port. Due to how Python is set up, the binary may be in `./Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sqlmap-2.7`. Feel free to create a symlink to that wherever you need it.

Comment: @neverpanic Nothing can be found. So I installed sqlmap from pip instead, and found `pip` created an executable `sqlmap` at `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sqlmap`

Comment: @neverpanic Maybe it's some macports' defects.